# LARAVEL 8 - redirect in lock page after session expired

Tags: laravel, authentication, session, redirect

I'm new to `Laravel` and I have a problem with the `redirect` after the session expired.
I set the `session_lifetime` at `120`.

How can I delete the `session` after it's expired?

Now, after `120` minutes, when clicking on a link inside the website it redirects to `login` page, but I tried to redirect to the lock screen page with the user details.

App\Exception\Handler

```php
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{      
    return $request->expectsJson()
        ? response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401)
        : redirect()->guest(route('auth/lockscreen/'.Auth::id()));
}
```

Route/Web

```
Route::get('auth/lockscreen/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@lockscreen')
        ->name('auth/lockscreen');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show web.php full routes and also lockscreen method

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answer.
Here there is a web.php (routes/web.php)

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function() {
Route::get('/todos', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodoController@index')->name('todos');
Route::get('/todo/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodoController@create')->name('todo/create');
Route::get('todo/edit/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodoController@edit')->name('todo/edit');
Route::post('todo/update/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodoController@update')->name('todo/update');
Route::post('todo/store', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodoController@store')->name('todo/store');
Route::delete('/todo/delete/{todo}', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodoController@destroy')->name('todo/delete');

Route::get('auth/lockscreen/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@lockscreen')->name('auth/lockscreen');
Route::post('auth/confirm_p/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@confirm_p')->name('auth/confirm_p');

Route::get('/todo/category', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodoCategoryController@index')->name('todo/category');
Route::post('/todo/category/store', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodoCategoryController@store')->name('todo/category/store');
Route::get('/todo/category/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodoCategoryController@create')->name('todo/category/create');
Route::get('/todo/category/edit/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodoCategoryController@edit')->name('todo/category/edit');
Route::delete('/todo/category/delete/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodoCategoryController@destroy')->name('todo/category/delete');
```

});

here the lockscreen method inside models User.php

```
public function lockscreen($id) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('auth.lockscreen.'$id)->with('user', $user);
}
```

I don't understand if the unauthenticated function provide to redirect user... Thanks